# How to push a variable, that continuously gets modified, from a service to a component?

Tags: angular, rxjs

This is what I have been trying to do right now:

`service.ts`:

```js
export class ChatMessagesService {

  private message: string;
  constructor() { }

  setMessages(message: string): void{
    this.message = message;
    console.log("From Service: ", this.messages);
  }

  getMessages(): Observable<string> {
    //creates observable from the message string and return it
    return from(this.message);     
  }
}
```

I was thinking of creating an observable in `getMessages()` method and subscribe to it in the component file:

```js
export class ChatDisplayComponent implements OnInit {

  public messages: string[] = [];
  constructor(private chatMessagesService: ChatMessagesService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chatMessagesService.getMessages().subscribe((message) => this.messages.push(message));
    console.log("From chat.display", this.messages);
  }

}
```

But this does not work, cannot receive newer values of the `message` string whenever it becomes available in the service.
How to do this functionality? (Maybe using subject but I am not so sure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RxJS `from` and `of` functions are used to create observables in a specific instance to the specific observer. In your case, you need to use a multi-cast observable like `Subject`. I'd suggest to use `ReplaySubject` with buffer 1 since it can "hold" the last emitted value and emit it to future subscribers.

**Server**

```js
import { ReplaySubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class ChatMessagesService {
  private message: ReplaySubject<string> = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);

  constructor() { }

  public setMessages(message: string): void {
    this.message.next(message);
    console.log("From Service: ", this.messages);
  }

  public getMessages(): Observable<string> {
    return this.message.asObservable();     
  }
}
```

Comment: This works! I can now get messages in the component, but I still don't understand why this works and a plain observable doesn't. Could you provide any references where I can read up more for understanding? Many thanks

Comment: Plain observables do not provide a way to notify subscribers of new values.  The emission behavior is defined when the observable is created. For example: `from` creates an observable that emits a provided value and completes immediately. There's no way to tell it that `this.message` has changed and to emit the latest value. `Subject` provides a way for you to emit new values any time.  In your case, you want to push a new value whenever the `setMessages()` method is called.